# A hot body cools so that every 24 min its temperature decreases by a factor of two. Deduce the time-constant and determine the time it will

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A hot body cools so that every 24 min its temperature decreases by a factor of two. Deduce the time-constant and determine the time it will take the body to reach 1% of its original temperature.
>
> Hint: The temperature function is $T(t)=T_0e^{-t/T}$ and T is the time constant.

What I did is:
$T = 24$

$\frac{T_0}{100}=T_0e^{-t/24}$

$\frac{1}{100}=e^{-t/24}$

$\ln{\frac{1}{100}}=\frac{-t}{24}$

$4.605=\frac{t}{24}$
$t=110.52$

However, the answer says:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The $24$ goes in the numerator because it is the elapsed time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$T(24) = \frac{T(0)}{2}$$

$$T_{0}e^{-\frac{24}{\tau}} = \frac{T_{0}}{2}$$

$$e^{-\frac{24}{\tau}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$-\frac{24}{\tau} = \ln(\frac{1}{2}) = -\ln(2)$$

$$\tau = \frac{24}{\ln(2)}\approx\boxed{34.625\text{ min}}$$

Now, we want to solve for $t$:

$$T(t) = \frac{T(0)}{100}$$

$$T_{0}e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} = \frac{T_{0}}{100}$$

$$e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} = \frac{1}{100}$$

$$-\frac{t}{\tau} = \ln(\frac{1}{100}) = -\ln(100)$$

$$t = \tau\ln(100) = \frac{24\ln(100)}{\ln(2)} \approx\boxed{159.453\text{ min}}$$